# How to connect to Netezza/PureData for Analytics using Python

Tags: python, netezza

I am trying to connect to Netezza using python's pyodbc.
Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc
print pyodbc.dataSources()
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};SERVER=netezza;PORT=<>;DATABASE=SYSTEM;UID=<>;PWD=<>;",ansi=True)
```

The error that i am getting is:

> Error                                     Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 import pyodbc
>         2 print pyodbc.dataSources()
>   ----> 3 conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};SERVER=netezza;PORT=5480;DATABASE=SYSTEM;UID=ins_etl_usr_qa;PWD=password;",ansi=True)
>         4 #cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MSSQL-PYTHON")
>         5 #conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};SERVER=server.example.com;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=myusername;PWD=password",
>   ansi=True)
>
> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib
>   'NetezzaSQL' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Answer (score 0):

The error say that it can find `NetezzaSQL` library so you have to make sure that you have that library installed and accessible.

Accessible in `Linux` would be having the library installed in the default location for libraries or setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to point to the folder where you have the library.

Comment: Could you please post the path from where I can install the netezza library.Also, the command to install it.